# drupal_write_record doesn't take object

Tags: database, arrays, drupal, object

In drupal 6 i used to do something like this:

```
<?php
/*
 * CLASS Example
 */
class example {
  var $id = NULL;
  var $title;
  var $body;

  .....

  // Save
  function save() {
    $primary_key = ($this->id == NULL ? NULL : 'id');
    if (drupal_write_record('mytabble', $this, $primary_key)) {
      return TRUE; 
    } else {
      return FALSE;
    }
  }
}
?>
```

This worked quite well. But in Drupal 7, the drupal_write_record only takes an array and no longer the object $this. The new db_merge also only takes an array.
Since i want to save the properties of my object to the database, the above code was very handy and generic for all kinds of classes.
Is there an alternative way to write an object to database, or a method to place objectproperties into a an array?

Any help will be appreciated!

Robert

Answer (score 1):

drupal_write_record does take an object or an array. Guess your problem is caused somewhere else.

drupal_write_record($table, &$record, $primary_keys = array())

$record: An **object or array** representing the record to write, passed in by reference. If inserting a new record, values not provided in $record will be populated in $record and in the database with the default values from the schema, as well as a single serial (auto-increment) field (if present). If updating an existing record, only provided values are updated in the database, and $record is not modified.

More info on [drupal_write_record for D7](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_write_record/7).